# NullPointerException when using PrimePush

Tags: java, primefaces, jboss, wildfly, primepush

When I try to initialize my eventBus I'm getting a NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   de.mrsfinster.web.livefeed.bean.FeedBean.init(FeedBean.java:179)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:77)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNext(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53)
>     at
>   de.mrsfinster.web.livefeed.bean.FeedBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.lifecycle_mixin_$$_postConstruct(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionUtils.executePostConstruct(InterceptionUtils.java:38)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionUtils.executePostConstruct(InterceptionUtils.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:68)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:153)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:44)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:76)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
>     at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:170)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2584)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2190)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2135)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:299)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This is my code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
}
```

I'm using Primefaces 5.2, Wildfly 8.2.0.final, atmosphere-runtime 2.4.0-RC3.

My web.xml configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently `EventBusFactory.getDefault()` returns null. This problem may appear after upgrading the PrimeFaces to 5.2 and discussed, for example, [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=41554). Try to load the `PushServlet` on startup for proper initialization:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

just put this code below to a default constructor

```
"eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();"
```

It will work for any version.