# PrimeFaces with Atmosphere

Tags: tomcat, primefaces, atmosphere

I'm using PrimeFaces (Push) 6.0 and Atmosphere Runtime 2.4.7 run on Tomcat 7.0.

You can say like 'Chat' from PrimeFaces ShowCase. It is working fine. I'm enable to chat and send messages from browser to browser. Everything is perfect until we close browsers and then everything stop working.

Here is the very simple way to reproduce the issue
1. Open browser A and access the app.
@OnOpen got called (all @PathParam are good and have values) 
@OnMessage fires perfectly

2. Now close browser A and start a new browser B. Access the app
   @OnOpen got called (all @PathParam are NULL)
   @OnMessage never fires.

I have googled too much and deep debug in Atmosphere and Primefaces Push already but till not find out the solution.

I do see after close browser A, Atmosphere they do the cleanup and causing the the next one stop working. I'm not saying Atmosphere issue, I'm just saying what I'm seeing when I debugging.

Please advice me,  I have been spending like 2 weeks debugging and searching the solution.

Nghia

Note: I'm not posting any code yet. Let me know what information you need I will post.

Comment: See 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [ask]. For me the 'showcase' IS working with your scenario in Wildfly 9

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this topic  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568104/eventbusfactory-jsf1073/37573787#37573787