# NullPointerException when using PrimePush EventBus - Primefaces 6.0

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, primepush

When I tried send a EventBus like showed below:

```
public void send() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, 
        new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(summary), 
        StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(detail)));
}
```

I got this exception:

```
10:18:50,488 WARNING[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-19)         java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.el.ELException:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.notifications.NotificationBean.send(NotificationBean.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
... 43 more
```

I tried to use this on web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

As discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985116/nullpointerexception-when-using-primepush) but after put this lines, the project doesn't works more and doesn't up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that is missing library atmosphere, so, I put atmosphere-runtime-2.4.5.jar in lib folder and add:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterLifeCyclePolicy</param-name>
  <param-value>IDLE_DESTROY</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.recoverFromDestroyedBroadcaster</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
  <param-value>10</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
  <param-value>10</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.CometSupport.maxInactiveActivity</param-name>
  <param-value>30000</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.readGetBody</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInitializer.disabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.analytics</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.annotation.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>org.primefaces.push</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>chartco.fleetmanager.pushendpoint</param-value>
</init-param>
```

So, it's works fine.